# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS would not complete booting

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation DVD (boot DVD was burn with ISO Recorder v2 using:

ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso downloaded from www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

would not complete booting. Shows Ubuntu pink background but no menu, no mouse cursor.

Waited for an hour - nothing.

Windows Explores shows all the files an directories on the DVD - all seems to be fine.

Checked the downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso with winMd5Sum -  OK.

Tried to check DVD integrity using ubuntu CD menu by pressing a key while booting. The menu shows up but does not respond to the keyboard including all the F1-F12 keys. Neither responds to the mouse. Actually the mouse cursor does not show up.

On another computer the menu shows and responds, but no matter what I select,  the CDROM keeps working hard but the screen goes black and I have now idea what is going on.
What might be wrong and how shall I get round it?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `.iso` checks out but you have problems with the disc on two machines, the problem is probably the disc media. Try burning another, and perhaps try using another brand of media as well. If your systems support it, you may want to look at [booting using a USB thumb drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) as an option.

Comment: dispite my desktop PC is Intel Pentium 4  3.2GHz and 1Gb memory, its  BIOS does not list USB as a boot device. Although in the BIOS BOOT tab there is an entry USB Boot [Enabled] - God knows what this entry means there